# Simple let or const variables in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I'm wondering if it is good practice to use simple `let` or `const` variables inside react functional components.

I know there are hooks like `useState`, `useRef` and `useMemo` / `useCallback`. My question is if you should always use them or not?

Is it good practice to define a `const` without a hook like this in a functional react component:

```js
const test = "test";
```

And is it considered as good practice to work with those variables inside the component function to write logic outside the JSX return statement in the react functional component body?

Like this:

```js
export default function MyComponent(props) {

  const otherCondition = props.content.length > 20;

  let myVariable = 0;

  if (props.isDisabled && otherCondition) {
    // ...more complex checks...
    myVariable = 1;
  } else {
    myVariable = 2;  
  }

  return (
    <>
     {/* some JSX */}
    </>
  );

}
```

Is the above example of writing let or const variables in react components good practice? Or should you avoid using `let` or `const` without any kind of hook (`useState`/`useRef` etc.)? If I'm understanding correctly all those `const` / `let` variables will be reassigned on each render. How can I prevent this reassigning performance cost while keeping the same behaviour?

Are there any more downsides of using `const` / `let` without any hooks beside reassigning at each render?

Would a usage of a hook like `useState` or `useRef` cost more performance than a simple `let` or `const` variable? If so when should you go with hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `let` or `const` is perfectly fine. Sometimes you need to declare variables that are derived from props or states, in order to make the code declarative and readable.

Regarding your performance doubt, you can always use `useMemo` hook to memoize the derived value and avoid calculating it on each render. But this should be avoided as long as your code is not expensive computationally.

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {

  const otherCondition = props.content.length > 20;

  const myVariable = useMemo(() => {
    let myVariable = 0;
    if (props.isDisabled && otherCondition) {
      // ...more complex checks...
      myVariable = 1;
    } else {
      myVariable = 2;  
    }
    return myVariable
  }, 
  [props.isDisabled, otherCondition])

  return (
    <>
     {/* some JSX */}
    </>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of const is preferable if your variable is not getting assigned again, use linters in VS Code and it will let you know where a variable can be const.

Use of let if you wish to make a variable re-assignable. It is less used in practice though. Let us assume a case that you need to use a variable and again re-assign it in a function or a loop, then let should be used.

Regarding hooks then they are of great help, they make us code better and code complex. As you mentioned that hooks do re-renders if data changes, and if there is some changes in DOM element, then only it is assigned to the create.reactElement. Regarding re-renders, you can have a beautiful medium [post here.](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928)

Is the above example of writing let or const variables in react components good practice?

Regarding this, it is the only practice. Prefer const if your variable is not getting re-assigned, that's the key.

Use of hooks will improve your performance in one way or other as you can do complex work with them instead of writing your own functions, hooks are basically functions that is created at a place and use anywhere. so, you are normally doing function calls and assigning the output to a variable as you do when you call your own functions.

Regarding your example, if you are not re-using `otherCondition` that don't make a variable out of it, simply use it in your condition like

```
if (props.isDisabled && props.content.length > 20) { ... }
```

Why to allocate memory for a single use variable? Other than this, your code looks fine to me.